# How do I get videoshow (or any other js package) to merge image and sound files to the length I specify rather than a constant length of 5 seconds?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, mp4, fluent-ffmpeg

I’m trying to take an image file and a sound file and merge them together into an mp4 file. To this end, I use videoshow.js which is basically a wrapper for fluent-ffmpeg.js. For some reason, videoshow always sets the duration of the output file to 5 seconds regardless of what I set the loop parameter to. And to top it all off, it fades out the sound towards the end of the clip.

I’m happy for any solution to this even if it doesn’t include the use of videoshow or fluent-ffmpeg.

```
const url = require('url');
const { smartLog } = require('../services/smart-log');
const { getFile, getDuration } = require('../services/file-service');
const videoshow = require('videoshow');
const path = require('path');
const FFmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const fs = require('fs');

const imgToMP4 = (caption, sound, image, duration, output) => {
  smartLog('info', `Converting ${image}`);
  const images = [image];

  const videoOptions = {
    fps: 10,
    loop: duration,
    transition: false,
    videoBitrate: 1024,
    videoCodec: 'libx264',
    size: '640x?',
    audioBitrate: '128k',
    audioChannels: 2,
    format: 'mp4',
    pixelFormat: 'yuv420p',
  };

  videoshow([
    {
      path: image,
    },
  ])
    .audio(sound)
    .save(output)
    .on('start', function (command) {
      smartLog('info', `ffmpeg process started: ${image}`);
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      smartLog('error', err);
    })
    .on('end', function (output) {
      smartLog('info', `Video created: ${output}`);
    });
};
```

Comment: Why is it quiet? Because your problem is not clear... It seems your function `imgToMP4` does the conversion but your code never runs it.  Also not clear what value you give to the `duration` variable. Knowing these things will help others to answer why _"Videoshow always sets the duration of the output file to 5 seconds"_...

Answer (score 0):

The only things I can see that need fixing...

- You use muse set **loop** to `-1` in order to repeat an image infinitely.
- Use **t** to set a duration (or playing **time**).

Try this modified version of your code for `const videoOptions`:

```
const videoOptions = {
    fps: 10,
    loop: -1,
    t: duration,
    transition: false,
    videoBitrate: 1024,
    videoCodec: 'libx264',
    size: '640x?',
    audioBitrate: '128k',
    audioChannels: 2,
    format: 'mp4',
    pixelFormat: 'yuv420p',
  };
```

Comment: I've made the suggested changes and am still getting the same result. I've given up on videoshow and am just using fluent-ffmpeg which seems to be working,